# JavaScript - Remove rows dynamically after 2mins

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am calling a webapi using get method which will give json data and I am display as a table from that data. the code which I have given below is working fine. I got around 25 rows(dynamically" of data when I fit the service. this webpage will be refreshed using signalR. when any changes in DB immediately it should reflect in the webpage.

My question is if `"" + item.TakeupType + ""` value is "Completed" or "cancelled" this row background should change to gray color and after 2mins row should be remove from the webpage.

Note:
1) Only 22 rows should display on webpage in orderby asc Datetime.
2) Completed/cancelled items from DB should will display on the webpage for 2 mins and drop off.

My code :

```
Hide   Expand    Copy Code
//Webapi call - To load info status.
function LoadinfoStatus() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('x-api-key', '9024024A-024-485C024-6BC2024DA');
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://mywebsites.net/version1/info/494",

        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            // alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            $("#DIV").html('');
            var DIV = '';

            //Function to get DateFormat
            function getFormattedDate(date) {
                // debugger;
                var inputdate = new Date(date);
                var currentdate = new Date();

                var strTime = getFormattedTime(inputdate);
                var rngStrTime = getFormattedTime(add_minutes(inputdate, 5));

                if (inputdate > currentdate) {
                    return inputdate.getDate() + '/' + (inputdate.getMonth() == 0 ? 12 : inputdate.getMonth()) + " " + strTime + " - " + rngStrTime;
                }
                else {
                    return strTime + " - " + rngStrTime;
                    //return day + "/" + month + " - " + strTime;
                }
            }

            var add_minutes = function (dt, minutes) {
                return new Date(dt.getTime() + minutes * 60000);
            }

            function getFormattedTime(inputdate) {
                var day = inputdate.getDate();
                var month = inputdate.getMonth() + 1;
                var hours = inputdate.getHours();
                var minutes = inputdate.getMinutes();
                var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
                hours = hours % 12;
                hours = hours ? hours : 12;
                minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;

                return hours + ':' + minutes + ampm;
            }


            $.each(data, function (i, item) {

                var rows = "<tr ' " + (item.Count > 100 ? "data-id='" + item.orderId + "'" : "") + (item.TakeupType == "Cancelled" ? "style='background-color: gray; color: white'" : "") + " align= 'center' > " +
                    "" + "" + "" + "" +
                    "" + item.user.firstName + " " + item.user.lastName.charAt(0) + "." + "" +
                    "" + item.TakeupType + "" +
                    "" + (item.Count == undefined ? "$" + " " + 0 : "$" + " " + item.Count) + "" +
                    "" + getFormattedDate(item.TakeupTimeUtc) + "" +
                    "= 100 ? "style='background-color: darkorange; color: white'>***" : ">") + "" +
                    "";

                var $tbody = $('tblOrders tbody');

                $('#tblOrders').append(rows);
            }); //End of foreach Loop


            registerEvents();
            // console.log(data);
        }, //End of AJAX Success function

        failure: function (data) {
            alert(data.responseText);
        }, //End of AJAX failure function
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data.responseText);
        } //End of AJAX error function

    });
}
```

Comment: (Check the title. Throw in a capital letter every now and then.)

Comment: There is obviously a missing `"` after the parenthesis on this line: `"= 100 ? "style='background-color: darkorange; color: white'>***" : ">") + "" +`.

Comment: My question is if "" + item.TakeupType + "" value is "Completed" or "cancelled" this row background should change to gray color and after 2mins row should be remove from the webpage.